# iOS Coloring Transparent Image

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to develop a coloring app. I want to start with a blank canvas and as the user colors using touch I want to reveal only those touched area of a colored image. How do I achieve this ? Any help will be of great help to me.

Answer (score 0):

may be this is will help you to kick start

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   

    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:drawImage];


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawImage.frame.size);

    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawImage.frame.size.width, drawImage.frame.size.height)];

    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), size);


      CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), r, g, b, a);


    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);

    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);

    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

although i havent try it out but found on SO question it is working fine for what you ask

Comment: Thanks. But how do I integrate the blending mode ? As I asked, I need to reveal the color.